# Can't call Activity from ApplicationAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-adapter

I'm starting on Android programming and right now I want to call an Activity from an ApplicationAdapter, but my code doesn't work.

I have this (ApplicationAdapter) class:

```
public class Render extends ApplicationAdapter implements SensorEventListener {
// ...
}
```

...and this (Activity) class:

```
public class GameOverActivity extends Activity {
//...
}
```

When, in the Render class I do:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Render.this, GameOverActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

I get this error in the first line:

> "Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(......)' "

I tried to find another solutions but none of them worked.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Where using `Render ` class get Context in `Render ` class using class constructor

Comment: I created a variable `private Context context;` and called the Activity with this code: `context.startActivity(new Intent(this.context.getApplicationContext(), GameOverActivity.class));`
But now I get [this](http://s8.postimg.org/iyn41pwj9/SDGFGHJGJ.png) error.
Do you know where can the problem be?
BTW the line 164 is the line where I call the Activity: `context.startActivity(new Intent(this.context.getApplicationContext(), GameOverActivity.class));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find an answer.

In the Render class I did `instance.startActivity(new Intent(instance, GameOverActivity.class));` and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

use context.startactivity(intent);

Comment: I created a variable `private Context context;` and called the Activity with this code: `context.startActivity(new Intent(this.context.getApplicationContext(), GameOverActivity.class));`
But now I get [this](http://s8.postimg.org/iyn41pwj9/SDGFGHJGJ.png) error.
Do you know where can the problem be?
BTW the line 164 is the line where I call the Activity: `context.startActivity(new Intent(this.context.getApplicationContext(), GameOverActivity.class));`